# ActiveMq Failover with scheduler delay

Tags: activemq-classic, failover

Let's say I have 2 MQ Servers (A, B). A configure failover to B and these MQ server is configured scheduler delay 5 minutes to process each queue. When A having 50 queue and suddenly failure in some reason. Will MQ Server B able to continue process the 50 queued store in A? Or MQ B only able to process incoming queue but not in A?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Well, i have no idea what exactly will happen in my staging. I just tried to simulate in my local machines. 2 cluster A failover B, 50 queued and shutdown A. B will not abled proceed queued in A. Is that any configuration way can make that happen? Cause my usecase cannot allow those message in queued without process.

Comment: There is a configuration in which both instances of ActiveMQ use same Database or message Store it is called 'Master slave configuration with shared DB.'  that will help your cause , have a look at it http://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave.html (this is for shared file system) or http://activemq.apache.org/jdbc-master-slave.html (this is for shared DB)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have fail-over setup using a shared file system directory for KahaDB. When you have delayed and/or scheduled messages, they are not placed in the default KahaDB database, but in your local "data" directory (i.e. by default one for A and one for B).

You must configure your scheduler to also use a shared directory (on some network disk or whatnot). Configuration example:

```
<broker ... schedulerSupport="true" schedulerDirectory="/path/to/shared/directory">
```